# Printf in for loop doesn't work without a printf preceded outside the loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, crash

I've been having this problem: when I try to print an array with 2 for loops nothing happens, blank screen. When I add a `printf` preceding the loop (anything like `printf("1");`) the loop printing shows in the execution. 
The code:

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
    printf("\n");
    for(k=0;k<i;k++){
        printf("%6d",*(polje+j*i+k));
    }
}
```

Not only does the program not print the loop, it says x.exe stopped working if I don't use another `printf` outside the loop.

Comment: Mostly it something to do with buffered output. Adding \n in printf solves the problem. There are other methods to force unbuffered stdout.

Comment: The chances are that the printing in the inner loop won't appear until you output a newline.  Normally, you put the newline after the inner loop: `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) printf("%6d", polje[i*j+k]); putchar('\n'); }`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `fflush(stdout);` after your second `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(j=0;j<i;j++){
    printf("\n");
    for(k=0;k<i;k++){
        printf("%6d",(polje+j*i+k));
    }
}
```

I removed * in the second printf.. It was multiplying anything oh the right side